# Haskell Equivalent of Zope Test Browser

Tags: python, http, testing, haskell, automation

I've been tinkering around with the [Zope test browser](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.testbrowser) in Python, exploring its suitability as for a few projects.

As I explored, I realized that there are a few things in Haskell that would be fun and useful to have.  Is there something in the Haskellverese equivalent to the Zope Test Browser?

Comment: Note that zope.testbrowser is basically a testing wrapper around  mechanize (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize) and ClientForm (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ClientForm, now merged into mechanize). These projects are heavily based on Perl's WWW::Mechanize and HTML::Form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest analogue is probably the Network.Browser module form http: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HTTP/4000.1.1/doc/html/Network-Browser.html

It's been around a long time an isn't the fanciest or most efficient, but it gives a similar direct emulation of a browser.

For doing browser-like things and fetching HTTP there are many other options. One of the newe ones is http-enumerator: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-enumerator

Shpider looks quite nice as well: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shpider

Shpider is based on curl, and there are direct curl bindings too, which are a pain to use sometimes (documentation on the options is... hit and miss) but quite powerful: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/curl

My preferred interface to the curl bindings is through dons' download-curl package: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/download-curl